# Wsgi file does not import flaskapp

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, flask, mod-wsgi

I have a Python Flask application that I want to run on a apache2(AWS EC2). This is my first time doing this so I have been using this [source](https://www.codementor.io/@jqn/deploy-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2-13hp1ilqy2) as a guide. However, my server keeps giving me the following errors and I do not know what went wrong. Please advise how I can solve this.

```
mod_wsgi (pid=5873): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi'.
[Tue Aug 17 21:04:26.331609 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5873:tid 140393656071936] [client 70.51.138.104:61053] mod_wsgi (pid=5873): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi'.
[Tue Aug 17 21:04:26.331636 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5873:tid 140393656071936] [client 70.51.138.104:61053] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Aug 17 21:04:26.331655 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5873:tid 140393656071936] [client 70.51.138.104:61053]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
[Tue Aug 17 21:04:26.331682 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5873:tid 140393656071936] [client 70.51.138.104:61053]     from flaskapp import app as application
[Tue Aug 17 21:04:26.331698 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5873:tid 140393656071936] [client 70.51.138.104:61053] ImportError: No module named flaskapp
```

My flask application path: `/var/www/html/flaskapp/`

Content of `flaskapp` folder:

```
application.py
utils.py
requirements.txt
flaskapp.wsgi
```

Content of `flaskapp.wsgi`:

#flaskapp.wsgi
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/html/flaskapp')

from flaskapp import app as application

Furthermore, I have also modified the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi

        <Directory flaskapp>
            WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: If you get a python shell in the /var/www/html/flaskapp directory, what happens when you run this line? from flaskapp import app as application

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change the line:

`from flaskapp import app as application`

to

`from application import app as application`

As the error says Apache can't import the module, which I think has happened because in the tutorial you mentioned, the file containing the flask app is called `flaskapp.py` whereas your file is called `application.py`.

I would also consider changing the name of `application.py` to something more specific, like 'my_descriptive_app_name' if you are going to store it in the variable application.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may need to change your `<Directory flaskapp` to `<Directory /var/www/html/flaskapp`. It should be an absolute directory path or a wildcard, not a relative path.

> Directory-path is either the full path to a directory, or a wild-card string using Unix shell-style matching.

From: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem by changing `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` to `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/flaskapp` in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file.